Facebook Graph API - Some page tokens will not return comments (#200) Missing Permissions
Using the below end point my page token returns posts from the page:
https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/{PAGEID}/feed?fields=id,created_time,message,status_type,from,place,picture,attachments&limit=100&access_token={TOKEN}
If I then take the post id from this return and try and get comments for it using the following end point I am getting (#200) Missing Permissions.
https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/{POSTID}/comments?limit=100&fields=created_time,from,comment_count,message,attachment&access_token={TOKEN}&order=chronological
But I am not being told what permissions are missing, and why I cannot get comments. This is also not always the case, this exact scenario works in many other cases, so there is an issue somewhere with the access of the user/page, rather than my process..... But I have no idea what, or how to find out.
If I look at the permission in the access token using the token access debugger tool, we have the following:
pages_show_list,
business_management,
pages_read_engagement,
pages_read_user_content,
pages_manage_posts,
public_profile
and my understanding from reading the documentation is that I just need this one: pages_read_user_content to read comments.
I am so confused.
Any help or suggestions of things I can try would be greatly appreciated. if only the error was more useful, and told me what I was missing, I could have a better idea of how to fix.
Thanks in advance

Does your app have all the permissions approved by Facebook yet? If not, might it be a case where sometimes the comments on the post have all been made by users with a role in your app; but when it fails, there are comments by other users as well?

yes it does, I think the issue is permissions the user has or in this case does not have on the page itself, but facebook api just does not let me know what is missing. I am doing lots of reading right now to try and resolve
